# What is a Runnable (Java) counterpart in Objective-C?

Tags: java, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, runnable

What is a good way to schedule tasks on the Main thread in Objective-C? Does any of the following ways create a new thread?

- performSelector afterDelay
- dispatch_after

Answer (score 0):

Neither creates a new thread. the two just schedule a call on the current NSRunLoop.

---

GCD uses an internal thread pool and dispatch_async schedules a call on any of these threads. That is one 'counterpart' for a Runnable (when used with a Thread object / a Threadpool).

Another 'legacy' way is NSThread's detachNewThreadWithSelector or performSelectorInBackground! :)